# empty values from ng-repeat json

Tags: angularjs

Why this is not working?

```html
  <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">

  {{ '{{ names }}' }}
  <tr ng-repeat="item in names">
     <p>Hello {{'{{ item.age}}'}}!</p>
  </tr>
```

```js
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
  app.controller('myctrl', ["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.name = [ { "age": "3" },
        {"age" : "2"}];
  }]);
```

It prints me all the ages but it can't access the numbers. It doesn't print anything.

Comment: In $scope you have assigned it to "name" key, whereas you are accessing in the view as "names". This could be becoz of it.

Comment: Also, what's with these quadruple curly braces?

Answer (score 0):

change `$scope.name` to `$scope.names`

Comment: Because your second line has not sense. What do yo u Want to do with  {{ '{{ names }}' }} . Yo u are trying to put a json array on the view